# Kendo Diagram will not display until the page resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, kendo-ui

I have a Html page in which div is there. And from seperate js file i am binding the Kendo Diagram to that div. The Diagram will not display until the page resize.

`Html Page`

```
<div id="center-pane" class="col-sm-10">
                    <div>
                        <div id="d1" style="height: 400px;"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

jf file

var d2 = $("#d1").kendoDiagram({
               shapes: [
                {
                    id: "1",
                    content: {
                        text: "Monday"
                    }
                },
                {
                    id: "2",
                    content: "Tuesday"
                }
            ],
            connections: [

                {
                    from: "1",
                    to: "2"
                }
            ],
            layout: {
                type: "tree"
            },
}).getKendoDiagram();
```

Comment: When are you binding the diagram? Is it in a `document.ready()` or something? See https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: @GaloisGirl i am calling that function called bind() from somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a `<div>` is not visible then it may means that it doesn't have a well defines height and width. Then rendering a diagram in to the is not meaningful.
To avoid that fllaw we have to add a height and width.

```
<div id="center-pane" class="col-sm-10">
     <div>
        <div id="d1" style="height: 400px; width : 400px;"></div>
     </div>
</div>
```